# Why am I getting this AttributeError ? (python3 , pygame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Below is the error I am receiving and the code I have written. I know similar questions have been asked , but the solutions they are given do not relate to this case. And I can't seem to figure out why I am receiving this attribute error. I am running python 3.3 and pygame. The OS im on is ubuntu 12.10. I hope someone can find a solution to this problem so I can continue working on this physics simulation.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/lawton/D4B1-5B96/programming/Python/gamephysics.py", line 9, in <module>
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'display'
```

```
import pygame


background_colour = (255,255,255)

(width, height) = (300, 200)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

pygame.display.set_caption('Tutorial 1')

screen.fill(background_colour)

pygame.display.flip()

running = True
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
      running = False
```

Comment: Just to be certain; what does `print(pygame.__file__)` print (after importing it, before using `pygame.display)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *shadowing* the `pygame` library with another `pygame.py` file, probably in the same location as `gamephysics.py`.

Print out the file path of the offending module:

```
import pygame

print('Path to pygame module:', pygame.__file__)
```

This will you show you where the 'rogue' module is located. Once you find it, rename it to something else.