# Error: AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'Colors'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm a newbie to python and game development. I'm following a Udemy tutorial "Python Game Development : Creating a Snake Game". Below is my program:

```
#Snake Game!
#Our game imports
import pygame
import sys
import random
import time

check_errors = pygame.init()

#(6,0)

if check_errors[1] > 0:
    print("(!) Had {0} initializing error, exiting....".format(check_errors[1]))
    sys.exit(-1)
else:
    print("(+) PyGame sucessfully initialized")

# Play surface. Create a black surface for game


playSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((720,460))
pygame.display.set_caption("SNAKE GAME")
time.sleep(5)

#Colors - r,g,b -- red green blue

red = pygame.Colors(255,0,0) #gameover
green = pygame.Colors(0,255,0) #snake
#black
black = pygame.Colors(0,0,0) #score
white = pygame.Colors(255,255,255) #background
brown = pygame.Colors(165,42,42) #food

# FPS frames per seconds controller 
fpsController = pygame.time.Clock()

#where do you want the snake to start
#Important variables

snakePos = [100,50] #should be less than the screen size - (720,460)
snakeBoday =  [[100,50],[90,50],[80,50]]

foodPos = [random.randrange(1,72)*10,random.randrange(1,46)*10]
foodSpawn = True

direction = 'RIGHT'
changeto = direction

#Game over function

def gameOver():
    myFont = pygame.font.SysFont('monaco',72)
    GOsurf = myFont.render('Game Over!!', True, red)
    GOrect = Gosurf.get_rect()
    Gorect.midtop = (360, 15)
    playSurface.blit(GOsurf,GOrect)
    python.display.flip()

gameOver()
time.sleep(10)
```

When I run this code, I am getting an error which says:

```
(+) PyGame sucessfully initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Apps\Python Project\Python Snake Game\snakeGame.py", line 28, in <module>
    red = pygame.Colors(255,0,0) #gameover
AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'Colors'
[Finished in 6.9s]
```

I googled this error. I followed this solution ([Why am I getting this AttributeError ? (python3 , pygame)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638531/why-am-i-getting-this-attributeerror-python3-pygame)):

[image]

I couldn't locate this file in my workspace. Is there any other solution that I can follow? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that there is no `pygame.Colors` attribute, you are looking for `pygame.Color` no s as documented [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html)

Comment: Thanks. The sublime text just suggested me Colors and clicked on it. It was a typo :D